# Documenting arrays in JSDoc typedefs for VS Intellisense

Tags: javascript, getjson, javascript-intellisense

In my VS2015 JavaScript app, I have a JSON object that I get from a REST API that I have documented using JSDoc `@typedef` comments:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} JSON_Response
 * @property {Number} id
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {JSON_Response_Tag} tag
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} JSON_Response_Tag
 * @property {Number} id
 * @property {String} color
 */
```

When I reference this type in JSDoc comments on the methods that consume these JSON objects, I can get Intellisense documentation just fine:

```
/**
 * @param {JSON_Response} response
 */
function process_response(response) {
  // process response here...
}
```

However, I simply cannot get this to work with arrays - when I attempt to index the array, I get the "yellow triangles" menu that happens when VS can't get Intellisense context for you:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} JSON_Response
 * @property {Number} id
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {JSON_Response_Tag[]} tags
 */

/**
 * @param {JSON_Response} response
 */
function process_response(response) {
  response.tags[0]. // no intellisense here
}
```

JSDoc's other recommended method, using [`{Array.<JSON_Response>}`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html), informs VS that `response` is an Array but does not give Intellisense for anything under that. Microsoft's own XML comments do provide this capability, but only for function parameters - I can't reach inside the objects, nor would I like to do so because I'd have to add this documentation every time the function is called.

Is there any way to document arrays with their underlying types in JavaScript's VS Intellisense?

If I have to write code, I want to minimize the side effects / be able to factor it out of the release.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so I actually read your question this time (sorry, I was in the middle of something earlier).

### Issue

Visual Studio will not recognize the JSDoc syntax you are using to define the type of element within your array—at least not where intellisense is concerned.

### Solution

XML is the solution here. You may be aware of this, but you can use JSDoc tags in conjunction with XML comments to circumvent their individual limitations. I'm not sure what tags and attributes you were using when you ran your tests earlier, but here is the correct implementation of your code:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} JSON_Response
 * @property {Number} id
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {JSON_Response_Tag} tag
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} JSON_Response_Tag
 * @property {Number} id
 * @property {String} color
 */

/**
 * @param {JSON_Response[]} response
 */
function process_response(response) {
    /// <param name='response' type='Array' elementType='JSON_Response'></param>

   response[0]. // intellisense works here
}
```

---

### DOCUMENTING NESTED PARAMETER PROPERTIES FOR INTELLISENSE

Regarding your comment and the edits you made to your question, you can specify nested property types of parameters using the `value` attribute of the `param` XML comment. The term "value" is a little misleading, because according to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh542720.aspx), it isn't used to actually specify a value but rather a value *type*. See below:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} JSON_Response
 * @property {Number} id
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {JSON_Response_Tag[]} tag
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} JSON_Response_Tag
 * @property {Number} id
 * @property {String} color
 */

/// <summary name='JSON_Response_Tag' type='Object'>my test summary</summary>
/// <field name='id' type='Number'>testid</field>
/// <field name='color' type='String'>testcolor</field>

/**
 * @param {JSON_Response} response
 */
function process_response(response) {
    /// <param name='response' type='JSON_Response' value='{id:0,name:"",tag:[{id:0,color:""}]}'></param>

    response.tag[0]. // intellisense works here
}
```

---

### Regarding Companynerd225's alternate solution

I'm not entirely sure that categorizing JSON objects as classes instead of types is the most accurate method here. Also, although I may not know the proper terms for it, I'm pretty sure a function returning `{id:0}` is not the same as a function returning `this`. See below:

[image: Class vs. Objects]

Not to mention, you would end up filling your JSDoc "Classes" section with types. By default, it would look like this in your navigation:

[image: Malformed JSDoc Classes Section]

---

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question. These are purposefully fake types that I do not define in the code. The issue is that I need to be able to access an array of these types rather than a single instance.

Comment: @Compynerd255 See my revised answer. The code there works for both document generation and accurate intellisense.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. I realize that I need to edit my question, though: the issue is that the array is *inside* the JSON object, which that XML comment can't touch.

Comment: Thank you. This does work, but it requires duplication of knowledge inside each consumer of the data. I actually found a better solution to this problem (posted as answer).

Answer (score 1):

It seems counter-intuitive, but the best way to get documentation on your JSON types, rather than bothering with the limitations of XML comments and Intellisense's limited ability to parse JSDoc, is to **actually write constructors that produce your types**, then reference it so that it is only parsed for documentation purposes.

In other words, have constructors in your JavaScript that look like this:

```
/**
 * @constructor {Object} JSON_Response
 * @property {Number} id
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {JSON_Response_Tag[]} tags
 */
function JSON_Response(){
  return {
    id: 0,
    name: "",
    tags: [new JSON_Reponse_Tag()]
  }
}

/**
 * @constructor {Object} JSON_Response_Tag
 * @property {Number} id
 * @property {String} color
 */
function JSON_Response_Tag(){
  return {
    id: 0,
    color: "#000000"
  }
}
```

You don't necessarily need all of the individual object types defined out: you can use whatever you'd like. You can even copy and paste a sample of your JSON output. You only need to divide out classes if you intend to store inner objects in other variables.

And then, instead of actually including the JavaScript file in your page, you can put all of these JSON constructors in a separate file and put an XML reference directive

```
/// <reference path="~/path/to/schema_file.js" />
```

at the top of your consuming JavaScript files - Visual Studio will run the code for the sole purpose of providing documentation.

Comment: You may have already addressed these, but I see a couple issues here. I'm assuming you would omit the scheme file from your JSDoc command? Otherwise you would end up with a bunch of classes instead of types in your JSDoc documentation. All the other issues I see right now sort of stem from that; e.g., how do you properly maintain typedefs for documentation while maintaining constructors for intellisense without duplicating your code?

Comment: These replace the typedefs. And since JSON always returns an object as the root, these types are always classes.

Comment: I'm still learning, but wouldn't those functions of yours be returning object literals, not classes? They are what typedefs are for, no? You would have to return "this" for them to be classes. They have no instances since they all return the same newly created object. Assuming I'm correct in saying they are not classes, then wouldn't you be polluting your "Classes" section with what should be types?

Comment: When you return an object from a function called with `new`, it overrides the "create new object with function's prototype and bind it to `this`" behavior, simply providing that object to the caller (and allowing `this` to fall out of scope). It's still a constructor in every sense, and JSDoc and VS Intellisense document it as such, extrapolating the limited information to full types. These are truly classes of objects in the same way that allowing the constructor to return `this` produces a class.

Comment: I may not know the terminology to adequately describe the difference between a function that returns `this` and one that returns an object, but I'm pretty certain they are different. I've added some concerns to my answer above.